# How to let identical ignore attribute/names?

Tags: r

```
> str(a)
 Named int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Var2" "Var3" "Var4" "Var5" ...
> str(b)
 Named int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Var1" "Var2" "Var3" "Var4" ...
> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE
```

I realized that `identical` compare not only the vectors content, but the names as well.

How to avoid the names check without manually deleting them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives the desired result:

```
> identical( unname(a), unname(b))
[1] TRUE
```

This gives a useful result but misleading information:

```
> mapply("==", a ,b)
Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can consider the `compare` package:

```
library(compare)
a <- c(Var2=0, Var3=0, Var4=0)
b <- c(Var1=0, Var2=0, Var3=0)
compare(a, b, allowAll=TRUE)
# TRUE
#  renamed
#  dropped names
```

The function attempts a few different transformations to see whether it can make the values equal. In this case, it renamed the objects and dropped the names.

Answer (score 3):

use `all.equal`:

```
a <- c(Var2=0, Var3=0, Var4=0)
b <- c(Var1=0, Var2=0, Var3=0)
all.equal(a, b)
# [1] "Names: 3 string mismatches"
```

And it tells you that the names are the missmatch.

```
b <- c(Var1=0, Var2=0, Var3=1)
all.equal(a, b)
# [1] "Names: 3 string mismatches"  "Mean absolute difference: 1"
```